# How to get the background color of button in javafx?

Tags: javafx

I have 3 buttons ,two of them are colored as green and red respectively.The third one is not colored.I want that if user hover to the first two colored buttons then he is not able to click it(shown by not allowed mark) and he can click the third button.
How to know which button is colored for this in javafx?

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Rather than attempting to allow clicks based on color, tell us what you really need. It is very likely that you have written the part of the codes which control the color change, so you could easily control the "clickability" from there as well.

Comment: Yep, I found alternative ways ! Just confirming that there is no such way of getting background color of button.